# Excel Vlookup on multiple values combined with sum

Tags: excel, math, multiple-columns, vlookup

I have two excel files 2010,

**1st book:**

```
WO  TotalQty  Country  ShipAdd
1             xxx      xxx
2             xxx      xxx
3             xxx      xxx
```

**2nd book:**

```
WO  Qty
1   10
1   5
1   10
2   4
2   8
3   10
```

What I need to do is to sum all the entries by `WO` from the 2nd book and put it in the column `TotalQty` in the 1st book.

**Expected result:**

```
WO  TotalQty  Country  ShipAdd
1   25        xxx      xxx
2   12        xxx      xxx
3   10        xxx      xxx
```

I was trying using a Vlookup but it is just pulling the first number in the 2nd book.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula (suppose that in `Book1` your `WO` column data starts from `A2` cell and in `Book2` your `WO` and `Qty` in columns `A` and `B` accordingly) :

```
=SUMIF([Book2.xlsm]sheet1!$A:$A,A2,[Book2.xlsm]sheet1!$B:$B)
```